# How to bring live site on localhost

Tags: magento2

I am trying to bring a live site on the localhost I am following these following steps but it gives error at the install time.

Step 1: I have downloaded the live site

Step 2: Then I have created a blank database and imported my DB into that

Step 3: Deleted the local.xml

Step 4: Then restart the installation

It gives error on 99% that no administrator role is found

```
[ERROR] Exception: No Administrators role was found
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

With reference to [this](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2/issues/351) link.

Can you please do this process in mysql.

> Run $ n98-magerun2 admin:user:create --admin-user=dev_admin
> --admin-password=dev123456 --admin-email=dev_admin@example.com --admin-firstname=DEV --admin-lastname=dev123456

And check it will working.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a live site and Database DP following Steps to make it work on localhost

1. in you `db.sql` file  find your base URL (secure and unsecured) using `ctrl + f`

change them something like that

```
Secure `https://www.example.com` to `https://localhost/example` 

insecure `http://www.example.com` to `http://localhost/example`
```

Import you SQL dump in a local empty database

2. Copy all content from live site  to `var/www/html/example`
   Now goto  `app/etc/env.php`

change following data with your local credentials

```
'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'magento235',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'admin123',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [

                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

3. Run following commands in example folder

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
> ```

I will work Fine I have migrated a site Few days ago with same steps

Happy coding